# is there any way to insert text in to the HTML5 SVG as like HTML5 <p> tag?

Tags: javascript, css, html, jquery-plugins, svg

i am creating some dynamic rectanguler boxes and want to insert text in to the shapes but i found it little bit difficult because of the SVG text as it need to set x and y co-ordinates to the seperate text tag, even it doesn't have width and height with automatic overflow capability and all that css style attributes we use to format the text...

can anyone suggest me the easy wayout for this, even by means of any sutaible **plugin** or builtin pollyfills will also work..

Answer (score 0):

[JS.Holder](http://imsky.github.io/holder/) does what you are looking for. Change your output type to SVG instead of the default PNG and it'll do the job for you.

Comment: can you please share its use in respect to aligning text over svg shapes.